# Is it possible to write swap method in Java?

Tags: java, swap, primitive-types

Here is the question: write a method that swaps two variables. These two variables should be primitives. It doesn't need to be generic e.g. two `int` variables. Is there a way?!

Comment: Chk this out.More info on swap by reference. http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS2213/swap/swap.html Chk this out.More info on swap by reference.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Without using an array or objects, no, it is not possible to do it within a method.

Comment: btw, arrays are objects, so you really only needed to say objects. from java.sun.com: "An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type." being picky i know :)

Comment: So how is it possible by using arrays or objects? Are these arrays or objects not used inside a method? Are they global? Or can one swap objects inside a method using local arrays or objects?

Comment: @geowa4 I thinks it is okay to say both to introduce to new comer that array is an object.

Answer (score 59):

While it is not possible to write a function that simply swaps two variables, it is possible to write a **helper function** that allows you to:

- Swap two variables using **only one statement**
- **Without temporary variables** in the caller's code
- **Without 'boxing'** primitives
- With a few overloads (one of them using generics), **it works for any type**

That's how you could do it:

```
int returnFirst(int x, int y) {
    return x;
}
<T> T returnFirst(T x, T y) {
    return x;
}
// other overloads as needed
int a = 8, b = 3;
a = returnFirst(b, b = a); // try reading this as a = b; b = a;
System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b); // prints a: 3, b: 8
```

This works because the Java language guarantees (Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.4.2) that all arguments are evaluated from left to right (unlike some other languages, where the order of evaluation is undefined), so the execution order is:

1. The original value of `b` is evaluated in order to be passed as the first argument to the function
2. The expression `b = a` is evaluated, and the result (the new value of `b`) is passed as the second argument to the function
3. The function executes, returning the original value of `b` and ignoring its new value
4. You assign the result to `a`

If `returnFirst` is too long, you can choose a shorter name to make code more compact (e.g. `a = sw(b, b = a)`).

Suppose you need to swap many variables of different types one after the other. By using returnFirst there's no need for intAux, objAux, etc. There's less risk of mistakenly using the wrong variable somewhere, because there are no extra variables (in the caller, at least).

Comment: If you name your function `_`, then you can **almost** write **`a=b;b=a;`**. See how clean(?) it looks: **`a=_(b,b=a);`**

Comment: Ouch, _ is deprecated as an identifier in Java 8 and could be removed in Java 9. Not sure what they are going to use it for.

Comment: this is awful and unreadable, who will want to do this ?

Comment: I think this should be an accepted answer! Awesome (but yes, totally impractical)

Comment: @marcus i think use of _ as an identifier is discouraged not disallowed since java 8 (compiler might show a warning) but Use of _ as indentifier with Lambdas will show a compile time error.

Comment: I have found out that they plan to officialize _ as the "unused" variable/parameter: http://www.coffee-bytes.com/2013/08/01/reclaiming-underscore/ http://www.tothenew.com/blog/why-you-should-stop-using-underscore-as-variable-name-in-java/ The path to that goal, however, seems painfully slow (version 8 and 9 disallowing it, maybe version 10 will add the new semantics)

Comment: Don't learn this pattern if you ever need to port your code to C++, or you plan to work with C++. This is unspecified behavior in C++. You probably will get a == b in C++ at the end.

Comment: Yeah, when I said "unlike some other languages" I was really thinking about C and C++ but I didn't think it was necessary to mention them explicitly.

Answer (score 18):

Check out this JavaWorld article that explains it in detail:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

A swap of two primitives will never work because primitives are passed by value in Java. You can't even write a method to swap two objects for that matter.

Like @Thomas said, the only thing you could do is have your primitives contained within other objects/arrays and modify those.

Answer (score 15):

One-liner for any primitive numbers:

```
a += (b - (b = a));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a generic version of @marcus's swap method that swaps any number of objects of the same type:

```
<T> T swap(T... args) {   // usage: z = swap(a, a=b, b=c, ... y=z);
    return args[0];
}

b = swap(a, a=b);
z = swap(x, x=y, y=z);
```

Comment: A vararg function will create a temporary array (Object[]) to pass all the objects. I'm not sure how the JIT will behave at runtime, but creating an array to swap two values looks a little wasteful, unless you really need a `rotate` function for an unspecified number of objects.

Comment: For a fixed number of values you can do it [without the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393906/how-do-i-make-my-swap-function-in-java/20600020#20600020).

Answer (score 2):

> In java5, the closest I can think of, which may help you, is :

The AtomicInteger class (and others) have `getAndSet()` atomic methods ..

Comment: The question is specifically about primitive types. These are objects.

Comment: @Thomas: "**should** be primitives"

Comment: @Thomas OK. I don't have a clue then. @geowa4 Thanks for your support :-)

Answer (score 2):

To write a swap method that swaps primitives you'd have to have the concept of "out" variables, i.e. variables whose values are passed up to the calling context. C# has those but you must still specify that they're out variables.

Answer (score 1):

This function will swap two ints

```
Integer[] swap(int a, int b){
    return new Integer[]{b,a};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that swaps two primitive variables

```
private void swap(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

It might not be of much use though ;)

Ok seriously, it could be done if the variables are class level:

```
public class MyClass{
    // excuse horrible coding practice of public mutable fields
    public int a = 1;
    public int b = 2;

    public void swap(){
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
}
```

Again though, I fail to see what the use of this could be

Comment: This answered the question as written - why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I have read the above answers seeking an explanation as to why it is said that a swapping program cannot be written in java in the way it is written in c++.
 I did the following way
[program screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM3lr.png)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Owens said. You could probably do it in C by passing variables by &reference, but afaik not in Java without using objects.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to swap two variable using a method.
**But you should declare that method with empty parentheses and then call it by
reference(empty parentheses)** .
Here is an example that illustrates swapping of two variable using a method.

public class Swapping

{

```
static String A="Apple";
static String B="Bat";

    public static  void swap()
    {
       String k;
        k=A;
        A=B;
        B=k;

    }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("Before swapping");
    System.out.println("A= "+A);
    System.out.println("B= "+B);
    swap();
    System.out.println("After swapping");
    System.out.println("A= "+A);
    System.out.println("B= "+B);
  }
```

}

By compiling the above code the output comes as follows:

Before swapping

A= Apple

B= Bat

After swapping

A= Bat

B= Apple

//In case of call by reference original value is changed if we made changes in the called method

Comment: This is a method that swaps the values of two variables in a class, not two variables passed as parameters. And calling a method with no parameters is NOT calling a method by reference.

Answer (score -4):

```
public class Swap
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int y = 5;
        int x = 4;
        int c;

        System.out.println("y = "+y);
        System.out.println("x = "+x);

        c=x; //c = 4
        x=y; //x = 5;
        y=c;

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("y= "+y);
        System.out.println("x= "+x);
    }    
}
```