# How to Swap rows?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, temp

I am given `int[][] Science`, `int rowOne` and `int rowTwo`. How can I swap `rowOne` and `rowTwo`?

I know that I am supposed to hold one row in `temp` variable, but I do not understand how it works. How does `temp` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a basic swap function in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624525/how-to-write-a-basic-swap-function-in-java)

Comment: I still do not know how to do it @azurefrog

Comment: @Mlaura Isn't what Matthew Huie shows being the solution of what you need? What else are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have

```
rowOne =2;
rowTwo =3;
```

Now think without third variable:

if you want to swap them you need to assign one of them to other like:

```
rowOne=rowTwo;
```

But if we do so , now rowOne is 3 , but previously it was 2. You need to remember that value and hence we need to store it in temporary memory . That's our third variable. That's how it works.

```
temp=rowOne ; //This third variable helps to remember the value.
rowOne=rowTwo;
rowTwo=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *int[][] Science* has 2 rows and that you would like to swap the order of these two rows, you could do the following in Java:

```
int tempRow[] = Science[0];
Science[0] = Science[1];
Science[1] = tempRow;
```

I'm not exactly sure what you meant by *rowOne* and *rowTwo* in your question, but you can use a temporary int[] to hold one of the rows, while performing the swap.  This works as Java has references to each row in the two-dimensional array.