# getItself function in java vs C++

Tags: java, c++

I have a function:

(C++)

```
int a,b;

int getItself(int itself,int dummy)
{
    return itself;
}

int a=10;
int b=20;
a=getItself(b,b=a);
```

(java)

```
public static int getItself(int itself, int dummy)
{
    return itself;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    a = getItself(b, b = a);
}
```

And the result is surprising: C++ can not do the swap while java can! I don't quite get why it occurs in that way. I thought both would first copy b to "itself", set a to b, and copy b to "dummy".

I would credit this code to this post: [How to write a basic swap function in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624525/how-to-write-a-basic-swap-function-in-java/37276661)

Comment: [c++ - Undefined behavior and sequence points - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: How about `std::swap(a, b)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of order of evaluation. In java it is fixed from left to right where as in c++ its undefined and is a compile time choice.

Your getItSelf  function depends on whether b is passed first or b=a is evaluated first. In java b will be passed first.

See [c++ order of eval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Also see [java order of eval](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html)