# Java shallow and deep copying JLS

Tags: java, deep-copy, shallow-copy, jls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java pass by reference issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436761/java-pass-by-reference-issue)

In my codes below, `methodA` will be called, which then delegates a call to `methodB`, in doing so, `methodB` assigns the input parameter with String literal "bbb", however, back at `methodA`, the string literal was not there, which section of the JLS defines this behavior?

```
package sg.java.test2;

public class TestApple {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        methodA();
    }

    public static void methodA(){
        String a = null; 

        methodB(a);

        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void methodB(String a){
        a = new String("bbb");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a pass by value vs pass by reference issue.  Java is pass by value ONLY.  When you call

`methodB(a)`

the reference `a` gets copied; in the context of `methodB`, `a` is a different variable that has the same value as in `methodA`.  So when you change it in `methodB`, `a` in `methodA` still points to the original String.

Another issue that comes into play here is that Strings are immutable, so you can't change the value of a String once it is set.  From the docs.

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are
>   created.

What you could do is

`a = methodB();`

and return `"bbb"` in `methodB`.  There is no reason to pass `a` in because you are not operating on it; I think you were only doing it to try to change `a` in the context that calls `methodB`, which you cannot do.

Finally, the relevant part of the JLS is [8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.1), which says

> When the method or constructor is invoked (§15.12), the values of the
>   actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter
>   variables, each of the declared Type, before execution of the body of
>   the method or constructor. The Identifier that appears in the
>   DeclaratorId may be used as a simple name in the body of the method or
>   constructor to refer to the formal parameter.

Comment: Thanks, in addition, if the parameter i were trying to pass around were not a string, and something mutable, say a normal domain object, would the above still be true?

Comment: Correct Chin.  I added an example to my answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Java is pass by value, not pass by reference.

The method signature is shorthand for this:

```
methodB() {
    String a = arguments[0];
```

i.e. it is a difference reference.  When you assign to 'a', you are assigning to the reference 'a' created as part of the method signature, not to the 'a' you declared in the code block that contained the call to methodB().

You can modify the value if it is an object, however.

```
class MyObj {
    String prop;
    public MyObj(String s) { prop = s; }
    public MyObj() { }
}

public void methodB(MyObj o) {
    o.prop = "foo";
}

public void methodA() {
    MyObj a = new MyObj();
    System.out.println(a.prop); // null
    methodB(a);
    System.out.println(a.prop); // foo
}
```

Comment: java is pass by value dammit!!

Comment: sorry, meant to say **not** pass by reference... fixed

Comment: Why is it that a.foo, after coming back from methofB(a) gives a "foo"..

Comment: @chin because `methodB` sets a.foo = 'foo'

Comment: @hvgotcodes because I again made a mistake and typed 'foo' instead of 'prop'... not enough sleep, too little coffee.