# Trouble flipping images in Java

Tags: java, image, colors

So I have to use java.awt.color to flip some imported images.

Here is my primary method to achieve flipping an image over the vertical axis:

```
  public void execute (Pixmap target)
  {
    Dimension bounds = target.getSize();
    // TODO: mirror target image along vertical middle line by swapping
    //       each color on right with one on left

    for (int x = 0; x < bounds.width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < bounds.height; y++) {

        // new x position
        int newX =  bounds.width - x - 1;

        // flip along vertical 
        Color mirrorVert = target.getColor(newX, y);
        target.setColor(x, y, new Color (mirrorVert.getRed(),
                              mirrorVert.getGreen(),
                              mirrorVert.getBlue()));
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when this executes, instead of the image, flipping, I get something like this:

Original:
[image: Original]

"Flipped":[image: "Flipped"]

Thank y'all for the help

Comment: Well, you are not removing the previous color

Comment: "mirror target image along vertical middle line by swapping each color on right with one on left" - you basically missed the "swapping" part

Comment: You're replacing the colors inplace and hence when you read pixels from the left they've already been overwritten. It's like "swap x = 4 and y = 2" and you do `y = x; x = y`. You'll end up with both having the value 4 (y = 4, x = y = 4).

Comment: @MuratK. so how would I go about removing the previous color?

Comment: @zubergu how did I miss the swapping part? I thought that when I set the NewX coordinate, I was swapping

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Color` object exactly the same as an existing color?  You should be able to treat them as immutable without any issues.  Also take a look at [swapping variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393690/is-it-possible-to-swap-two-variables-in-java)

Comment: Nice example of some archetype of error that happens frequently. Some more basic example: You have a collection of objects, where, by mistake, the names "John" and "Charles" have been exchanged. To fix it, a script runs to replace all "John" by "Charles" and then another on that replaces all "Charles" by "John".  No big surprise, no "Charles" will be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
// flip along vertical 
        Color mirrorVert = target.getColor(newX, y);
        target.setColor(x, y, new Color (mirrorVert.getRed(),
                              mirrorVert.getGreen(),
                              mirrorVert.getBlue()));
       target.setColor(newX, y , new Color(255,255,255));
      }
```

This should work in theory. Basically the idea is to set the Colors on the right side to white, while copying it over to the left side.

---

Actually this will not work... So what you could do is to save the new colors in an array. Then you can make everything white and put the swapped colors back.

---

```
for (int i=0;i<image.getWidth();i++)
        for (int j=0;j<image.getHeight();j++)
        {
            int tmp = image.getRGB(i, j);
            image.setRGB(i, j, image.getRGB(i, image.getHeight()-j-1));
            image.setRGB(i, image.getHeight()-j-1, tmp);
        }
```

That one looks promising.

Comment: Placing the colors into an array still doesn't work, and I'm not sure why– it just makes everything white.

Comment: @TylerA Can you use java.awt.Graphics2D?

Comment: I don't think that's allowed in this assignment. Just awt.Color.

Comment: @TylerA Found a code snipped for flipping. Try it out. But you have to slightly change the method names.