# Inverse of Fractions using Java

Tags: java

Fraction switches numerator and denominator.
inverse of 2/1 is 1/2

what i got so far:

```
public void inverse(){
    numerator = denominator;
    denominator= numerator;
}
```

this makes the inverse of 2/1 equal 2/2.

I know this is happens because num = den (so num=2) and den = num (so den=2).

How would i switch  to get num=2 and den =1?

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: says incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to long.

Comment: oh, right then. wait a moment

EDIT: does it work now?

Comment: Isn't it just a `swapping` issue?

Comment: Thanks. It works now. mind explaining how you got the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to swap two variables in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393690/is-it-possible-to-swap-two-variables-in-java)

Comment: @JCole Gladly. the error means that I was trying to set the value for a variable of type long, a value of type double. they are different in a few ways, primarily long uses more bytes of memory. by changing the type of the temporary variable, the problem disappear. If the answer is good, you can accept it (tick under the score of the answer)

Comment: @JCole did you understand the explanation?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, create a temporary variable:

```
public void inverse(){
    long temp = numerator;
    numerator = denominator;
    denominator = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to swap the numerator and denominator but you are not using a temporal variable, so one of the operators will be lost..

```
public void inverse(){
    Number temporalNumber = numerator;
    numerator = denominator;
    denominator = temporalNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use temp variable:

```
public void inverse() {
  long x =  numerator; //or int because i don't know what you use
  numerator = denominator;
  denominator = x;
}
```

---

Or tricky way for ints:

```
public void inverse() {
  numerator ^= denominator;
  denominator ^= denominator;
  numerator ^= denominator;
}
```

Comment: why would you use this: ^?

Comment: @ItamarGreen, this is the tricky method to swap values via xor

Comment: oh. but the type double apparently doesn't work (it should be long, like my answer... 0.0)

Comment: the question doesn't state about type, isn't it?

Comment: @ItamarGreen, ok, didn't see)

Answer (score -1):

as already the answers are given, here is just another way to swap numbers without temporary variable

```
    int numerator = 10;
    int denominator = 20;
    System.out.println("Before " + numerator + " " + denominator);

    numerator = numerator + denominator;
    denominator = numerator - denominator;
    numerator = numerator - denominator;
    System.out.println("After " + numerator + " " + denominator);
```

output

```
Before 10 20
After 20 10
```

method

```
public void inverse() {
    numerator = numerator + denominator;
    denominator = numerator - denominator;
    numerator = numerator - denominator;
}
```

with bit-wise operations

```
    numerator = numerator ^ denominator;
    denominator = numerator ^ denominator;
    numerator = numerator ^ denominator;
```

Comment: @JCole `^` is called bit-wise ex-or operator, set log, print the a,b values after each statement and print them in binary, you could understand easily.